# Why is my Celery Docker not connecting to Redis?

Tags: docker, redis, celery

I have a Docker instance for running celery that's being built like this:

`docker build -t <me>/celery-imagemagick -f docker/celeryDockerFile .`

I am then running it like this:

`docker run --env-file ./docker/env --rm spaceofmotion/celery-imagemagick`.

Inside the env file are some configs, including the broker urls that target a local `redis-server`.

`CELERY_BROKER_URL=redis://192.168.86.23:6379/0
CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND=redis://192.168.86.23:6379/0`

The above is set up for local testing right now. It gets to a state where celery starts up and looks around for redis, only to not be able to connect with the following error:

`consumer: Cannot connect to redis://192.168.86.23:6379/0: Error 111 connecting to 192.168.86.23:6379. Connection refused..`

If I change the ip address to localhost, then it predictably cannot find the server. However, if I just run all of this locally without Docker by doing `celery worker -A path.to.celery --loglevel=info`, then everything works fine np.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Docker containers do not run on your host network (192.168.x.x) by default. If you're on a Linux machine, you can use [Docker host networking](https://docs.docker.com/network/host/).

In this case, you can also add a port mapping. Try this:

`docker run -p 192.168.86.23:6379:6379 ...`

This maps your local Redis port to `localhost:6379` in the Celery container. https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/container-networking/#published-ports has more.

Comment: Thanks! This was a clutch half of it. The other half was switching to using host.docker.internal.

Answer (score 0):

Its an older question but the following solution worked for me:

```
redis:

 image: redis:6.2-alpine
 networks:
  - djangonetwork

celery:
 networks:
  - djangonetwork
 restart: always
 build:
  context: .
```

Putting Redis, Celery and Django in the same Network with the Celery URL:

```
CELERY_BROKER_URL = 'redis://redis:6379/0'
CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = "redis://redis:6379/0"
```